# Evaluate the Taylor series and find the error at a point

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I have the following function
$$f^{(0)}\left(x\right)=f\left(x\right)=e^{x}$$
And want to approximate it using Taylor at the point $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}} $$

I also want to decide (without calculator) whether the error in the approximation is smaller than $\frac{1}{25} $.

The Taylor polynomial is:
$$f\left(x\right)\approx P\left(x\right) = 1+x+\frac{1}{2}x^{2}$$

I evaluate the function at the point: $$f\left(- \frac{1}{2}\right)=e^{- \frac{1}{2}}$$

I evaluate the series at the point: $$P\left(- \frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{5}{8}$$

Method. 1.
The error I get is $$E=\left|f\left(- \frac{1}{2}\right) - P\left(- \frac{1}{2}\right)\right|=\frac{5}{8} - e^{- \frac{1}{2}}\approx 0.018$$

Method. 2.
Using the formula $$E=\left|\frac{f'''(c)(c-a)^3}{6}\right|$$
where c is: $$-\frac{1}{2}<c<0$$
I get the error to $$E=\left|\frac{e^{- \frac{1}{2}}(-\frac{1}{2})^3}{6}\right|=\frac{1}{48\sqrt{e}}\approx 0.013$$

So my questions: 1. Which one of my methods is correct(if any)? 2. How do I show that the error is smaller than 1/25 without using a calculator?

Many thanks for any input on this matter:)

Answer (score 1):

The second method is (partially) incorrect since $c> -\dfrac12$, not $c= -\dfrac12$.

However that method can provide an upper bound to the error, i.e.

$$E = \left|\frac{e^cc^3}{6}\right|<\left|\frac{e^0(-\frac12)^3}{6}\right|=\frac1{48}$$

The inequality is due to, for $-\dfrac12<c<0$, we have $e^c<e^0$ and $|c^3|<\left|-\dfrac12\right|^3$.

Comment: Thank you. But is the first method correct then?

Comment: It cannot be incorrect. It is the exact value of the error.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! But If I only want to get an upper bound to the error (the biggest the error can be) the modified formula you provided can be used? (since I need to show the error is smaller than 1/25 without calculator and your calculation provided a more simple answer to compare with)

Comment: Indeed. However I do wish to point out that you came up with the formula; I just applied the bounds.

Comment: Method 1 is somewhat circular in that you use the value of $e^{-1/2}$ (from a calculator, maybe) to calculate the error.